# Read multiple json files into an array of objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have multiple json files under a folder that I need to read. The data file path is like:

```
./data/json1.json
./data/json2.json
```

My initializer class works as below:

```
const j1 = require('./data/json1.json');
const j2 = require('./data/json2.json');
init(){
    return j1.concat(j2);
}
```

Is there a better way to do this as the list of files under data could increase and every time this would require modifications?

I would preferably avoid a solution with looping in the folder and read file to append in an array object in `init()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a variant:

```js
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const dir = './data';

function init() {
  return fs.readdirSync(dir)
           .filter(name => path.extname(name) === '.json')
           .map(name => require(path.join(dir, name)));
}
```

Comment: Is there any alternative for the client-side? (I am trying to use this for typescript client-side) IS there any alternative?

Comment: @infamoushvher I think this is worth a separate question.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [glob](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob) package.

```
const glob = require("glob");
const path = require("path");

glob('data/*.json', function (er, files) {
  files.forEach(function(file) {
    //Do your thing
  })
})
```

Comment: where are we using glob here? it's normal file read, that I would preferably avoid.

Comment: If you don't want to modificate your code again get the paths with the glob.

Comment: `path.join` returns a string, with no forEach method. and the asterisk is also not working